# Displaying ads on C# desktop applications?

Tags: c#, ads

So I've been trying to figure out what's going on with ads in desktop applications, and looking at APIs, Google's API seems low on examples and documentation, and I didn't manage to make any sense out of it, and the Bing API seems to be concerning itself with those who want to *be* advertised, rather than affiliates. In retrospect, so does Google's.

My currently leading idea is to just drop in a web form in my Windows Forms application, and load the HTML that the Google/Bing/Whoever would give me for my webpage, that should register as the ad being viewed/clicked etc. But that seems a bit amateurish, I would imagine there would be a component ready for displaying ads.

So **the question** is, do advertising APIs from the major players (Google, Bing, Amazon etc) target affiliates or not? If not, does the web browser component method work, or may it lead to having the account revoked due to suspicious use of the HTML code (to prevent scam etc)?

Additionally, I found out that Amazon forbids use of the ads in applications not specifically related to Amazon itself, it seems alright to do so for Bing and Google but I can't find conclusive proof of it, does anyone know what's going on with that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a technical question, it is a question about evaluating the merits of multiple 3rd party services.

Comment: I beg to differ, it concerns the possibility of adding ads without using the web browser component, the possible threats that using the browser component may have, and whether the APIs concern the affiliate or the advertised party (or at least those are the issues that drove me to post this question). I do however perfectly understand how the lines may become somewhat thin, especially since APIs are different and answers may partially rely on "evaluating the merits of 3rd party services" as you accurately put it.

Comment: but the question, as you have worded it, would require people to know about or research the inner workings of each "major players" APIs, and the policies of each for how their APIs should be used.  This isn't a problem to be fixed, specifically, it is more of a discussion point, which isn't a good fit for this format.

Comment: I see your point, however the questions of "can I put ads in a desktop application" and "how are ads (best?) added to a desktop application" require suggestions and knowledge on these APIs. I admit that does make them quite abstract, but seeing as there is little to go with out there, I believe it might be acceptable. I would compare that to "what language is best for a web application?" in that, one would have to be familiar with a few languages and their workings, except there is ample info on this matter, as opposed to advertising which is - surprisingly - rather hard to figure out.

Comment: did you find any solution ?

Comment: Closest I came was hosting a website and putting ads there, then display it using the WebBrowser component, which is a workaround at best... didn't go as far as publishing to see that it actually works as intended because of some separate issues with the ad service.